# Decide for which x the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}( \sqrt[k]{e}-1) {x^k} $ converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

I want to find radius of convergence for the power series
$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}( \sqrt[k]{e}-1) {x^k}$. I try with the ratio test and I get

$\frac{|(e^{1/(k+1)}-1)x^{k+1}|}{|(e^{1/k}-1)x^{k}|} = |x| \frac{e^{1/(k+1)}}{e^{1/k}} \frac{1-1/e^{1/(k+1)}}{1-1/e^{1/k}} \longrightarrow |x| \frac{e^{0}}{e^{0}} \frac{1-1/e^{0}}{1-1/e^{0}} $ when $ k \longrightarrow \infty $

That is, I end up with a $\frac{0}{0}$ expression. I can "see" on the final expression that it approaches  $|x|\times \frac{1}{1} \times \frac{1}{1}$. Is there any way to achieve this without ending up with the zero division?

Appreciates all help I can get.

Comment: Hint: $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}k(\sqrt[k]{e}-1)=?$

Comment: Multiply the top and bottom by $e^{-1/k}$ and then the limit will be $\frac{-1}{-1}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $a > 1$,
consider
$f(a)
=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}( \sqrt[k]{a}-1) {x^k}
$.

Since
$\sqrt[k]{a}
=e^{\ln(a)/k}
\approx 1+ \ln(a)/k+O((1/k)^2)
$,
we have
$\sqrt[k]{a}-1
\approx \ln(a)/k+O((1/k)^2)
$
so the sum behaves like
$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^k\ln(a)}{k}
$
and this converges for
$|x| < 1$
and diverges for
$|x| > 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $ R_{a} $ be the radius of convergence of $ \sum{\left(\sqrt[n]{\mathrm{e}}-1\right)x^{n}} $, and $ R_{b} $ the radius of convergence of $ \sum{\frac{1}{n}x^{n}} \cdot $

Since $ \mathrm{e}^{\frac{1}{n}}-1\underset{n\to +\infty}{\sim}\frac{1}{n} $, we have $ R_{a}=R_{b} \cdot $

Observe that at the point $ x=1 $, the series diverges using the privious comparaison, and that at point $ x=-1 $ the series converges by the alternating series test.

Thus, the series converges if and only if $ x\in\left[-1,1\right[ \cdot $